# Al ejecutar mi proyecto con Junit y Selenium me muestra mensajes "Un software de pruebas automatizadas esta controlando Microsoft Edge."

Tags: selenium-webdriver, microsoft, edge

Buen día,
Alguien que pueda guiarme como desactivar los mensajes que me aparecen cuando ejecuto un test con Microsoft Edge

"Un software de pruebas automatizadas esta controlando Microsoft Edge."

Desactiva la depuración remota para abrir este sitio en modo de internet Explorer. En caso contrario, puede que no funcione según lo esperado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es un test, cierto? ¿De qué manera afecta a tu test el mensaje? No veo una **necesidad real** de deshacerse de dicho mensaje. Saludos

Comment: es para una presentación en mi trabajo y me solicitaron que lo sacara, eh intentado darle en las X de cerrar pero no hace nada se queda tal cual

Answer (score -1):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\SeleniumPlus\\extra\\msedgedriver.exe");
EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
edgeOptions.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge Dev\\Application\\msedge.exe");
edgeOptions.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
edgeOptions.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
EdgeDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.close();

    

> introducir el código aquí
```

Comment: porque no pruebas a dar una mejor descripcion del codigo insertado, puede que sea obvio para ti pero para los demas no. por favor lee [answer]